# Replace a parent class with another class without keeping the old parent

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I have in an external library:

```py
# external package content


class Foo:
    
    def func(): ...


class Bar(Foo):
    
    def func():
        super().func()
```

What I need in my code:

```py
from external_library import Bar

class MyOwnCustomFoo:

    def func(): ...


# Do some magic here to replace a parent class with another class without keeping the old parent


# Class name can be not 'Bar', but the class must have all 'Bar' attributes
class Bar(MyOwnCustomFoo):

    def func():
        super().func()
```

Goals I need to achieve:

1. I must have all `Bar` methods without copy/pasting them.
2. `Bar` must inherit from my own class, not from another one.

Comment: What you want is not possible, not even with metaclasses. Maybe someone might find a hack with dirty monkey-patching to do this, that I cannot come up with right now. But this whole idea is a non-starter. I think that you might have an architectual problem that might be solved in another way. To address this, we'd need some background on the issue you're trying to solve.

Comment: Just because you want a class that's like `Bar`, but inheriting from `MyOwnCustomFoo` instead, does not mean you should actually change `Bar`. Assume that classes are defined the way they are for a reason. Classes are not infinitely malleable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign the methods from the external library class to your own class, mimicking inheritance (AFAIK this is called monkey-patching):

```py
from external_library import Bar as _Bar

class Bar(MyOwnCustomFoo):
    func = _Bar.func
    ...
```

Comment: That is... elegant! :0

Comment: I may be worng, but instead of copy/pasting all methods names, it is probably better to just add    ```def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(_Bar, name)```.

Comment: Well, since there are not better answers, I am accepting this for now.

Comment: @Nairum, yep, that would probably be the shorter and better solution !

Answer (score -3):

You need to use what's called a "[monkey patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching)" to override the `bar.foo()`in the imported instance of the class. This link has a sufficient example:

See [Monkey Patching in Python (Dynamic Behavior)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/monkey-patching-in-python-dynamic-behavior/) - GeeksforGeeks

Comment: In order to be immediately helpful to readers (and avoid [link-rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-rot)), answers that provide at least a summary of the solution directly are preferred, with links used to offer additional information.